# Heroku clock file setting for flask app factory

Tags: python, flask, heroku, apscheduler

How can I setup the clock.py file using the flask app factory pattern?

Following is the flask app **init** file

```
import logging
import os

from flask import Flask

from .extensions import scheduler
from .settings import DevelopmentConfig


def create_app():
    """Create a new app instance."""

    def is_debug_mode():
        """Get app debug status."""
        debug = os.environ.get("FLASK_DEBUG")
        if not debug:
            return os.environ.get("FLASK_ENV") == "development"
        return debug.lower() not in ("0", "false", "no")

    def is_werkzeug_reloader_process():
        """Get werkzeug status."""
        return os.environ.get("WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN") == "true"

    # pylint: disable=W0621
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_object(DevelopmentConfig)
    scheduler.init_app(app)

    logging.getLogger("apscheduler").setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # pylint: disable=C0415, W0611
    with app.app_context():
        # pylint: disable=W0611
        if is_debug_mode() and not is_werkzeug_reloader_process():
            pass
        else:
            from . import tasks  # noqa: F401

            scheduler.start()

        from . import events, web  # noqa: F401

        app.register_blueprint(web.web_bp)

        return app
```

I have tried https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python. Nothing has been mentioned on the official document.